# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using a [script from the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/NOTE-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20171214/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html) to create accessible tab panels. When I load the page with the script, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined` for a variable `tablist` which is defined as follows:

```
var tablist = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tablist]')[0];
var tabs, panels;
var delay = determineDelay();
```

The code that the error refers to:

```
// Determine delay
function determineDelay () {
    var hasDelay = tablist.hasAttribute('data-delay');
    var delay = 0;

    if (hasDelay) {
        var delayValue = tablist.getAttribute('data-delay');
        if (delayValue) {
            delay = delayValue
        } else {
            delay = 300;
        }
    }

    return delay;
}
```

And the HTML `tablist` is supposed to grab is:

```
<div role="tablist" aria-label="Options">
   <button role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="general-tab" id="general-btn">General</button>
   <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="social-tab" id="social-btn" tabindex="-1">Social Networks</button>
</div>
```

This is being loaded via a WordPress plugin that is enqueued as:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'enhap-admin-script', plugins_url( '../_js/enhap.js', __FILE__ ), array(), false, true );
```

I cannot see anything wrong with the script. I tried manually typing the `var` command in the console and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a trailing `"` in the selector string. Change to:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[role="tablist"]')[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has arrived here due to a js file called global-shortcut.js you may have ColorZilla installed on your chrome. Uninstalling this fixes the issue.

e.g.

```
global-shortcut.js: 10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null
```

Hope that helps