# Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, mdbootstrap

I have a problem with **Material Design Bootstrap**, I added it with `NPM` but when I'm on my website, I got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null
    at r (app.js:19116)
    at Module.o.m.n (app.js:19116)
    at o (app.js:19116)
    at app.js:19116
    at app.js:19116
    at Object../node_modules/mdb-ui-kit/js/mdb.min.js (app.js:19116)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:19361)
    at Object../resources/js/app.js (app.js:1845)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:19361)
    at app.js:19500
```

And there is where is the problem: `hasAttribute("data-mdb-no-jquery")`. I don't know how I can correct this problem.

Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436408/4721265

Comment: it was another problem but I finally found it, it was due to code that was not updated with respect to mdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you send the code block where you are using this line?

`Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null` means that somewhere you are doing something like `myVariable.hasAttribute(...)` but the value of `myVariable` is null or undefined so there is no function to call.

Comment: Yes, I had a piece of code that was not recognized by mdb, probably due to the switch from bootstrap 4 to 5? 

I had tried little by little to remove some code and after a while it worked!

Comment: @ThomasOrgeval how did you make it work? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @AnkitSahay sorry I don't really remember, but I had deleted some of the MDB code, or I had done an installation with CDNs I think

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue here. I am debugging the same line where the error appears, but whenever I execute that same line `(jQuery && !document.body.hasAttribute('data-mdb-no-jquery'))` I get `true`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was including the script in the head, at which point it can't find the body. I moved the script for mdb to the end of the body tag instead. Now the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where do we put script source inclusion/link.

I had this problem with webflow.js file, it was placed in the head of the document and caused this error.
It was trying to read properties of document.body while DOM wasn't loaded yet.

So simply by putting it before the end of the body, the webflow.js was able to read DOM properly and the error warning disappeared. Something like this:

```
    ...
    <script src="<?php echo $absPathSSL;?>js/webflow.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
...
```

Hope this helps someone.